# HTML tags that are in the database are not echoing or printing out. How do I fix this?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have some content with break tags . When I echo and print it out those tags do not appear. How do I fix it?

It showing this in the database

```
  <br>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Comment: How do they look as raw data in the database? Are they "&lt;br&gt;" or "<br>"

Comment: it shows <br> in the database

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to literally print out `<br>` to the screen.  You should use [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on the string of text to convert `<` to `&lt;`, etc. and make the tags visible.  This is also important to prevent XSS via tag injection.

Comment: In the database it has <br> trying to get the breaks in the content but when I print or echo the <br> doesn't show. I'll try this and see if it does it.

Comment: @Kenshi does the content actually have `<br>` in it when you view the source?

Comment: @ExplosionPills no, it's in the database though

Comment: @Kenshi when you retrieve it from the DB do you do any other processing on it?

Comment: @ExplosionPills no just echoing and printing what ever comes out. All I am getting is the content without the <br> tags

Comment: @Kenshi are you sure that your server or CDN doesn't do any sort of processing on the output?  If you `var_dump` the string from the DB does it include the `<br>`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, How would I be able to check if it's doing that? I am on my local. I just did a var_dump and still no <br> tags.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29152/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-kenshi)